# Regarding HTTP get and post method for classical nvp API paypal

Tags: http, post, paypal, get, paypal-nvp

I have PayPal integration with express checkout which uses NVP API 
version 119.0.

Do we need to change HTTP method to POST from GET while requesting NVP based API for version 119.0?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal currently accepts both **GET** and **POST** HTTP methods on our classic NVP/SOAP APIs, used for Express Checkout. Going forward, PayPal will allow the use of the **POST** request method only for these APIs.

`To avoid any disruption of service, you must verify that your systems are ready for this change by June 2018.`

https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/Discontinue-Use-of-GET-Method-for-Classic-APIs/

Comment: How to switch to POST method?

Does anyone know specifically which file(s) and lines this would affect?

I am hoping (praying) that the change only involves changing a few lines around.  

Does anyone have any input into this?